# vs2008: class designer as limited as it looks?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't see a way to show ownership, containment, associations, etc. using visual studio's class designer. Have I missed something or is it really that limited?

Comment: Can you elaborate (see my answer ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class Designer feature in VS is not a UML designer and does not show various parts of UML.  It focuses on .Net constructs such as members, inheritance, properties, fields, methods, etc ...

It is possible to see relationships between classes.  This is true for 1-1, 1-N and N-1 mappings.

If that doesn't answer your question can you be a little more specific about what kinds of relationships you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

The vs2008 does shows relations i.e. properties, inheritance, etc.